# Alternative way of storing multiple cursors using the same variable

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql

I only want to use a "For Loop" ONCE in my pl/sql code. Say I have 2 (or more) cursors. How can I make it dynamic by using an IF statement for example, to select which cursor to run in that "For Loop" ?

Tried storing both cursor results using the same variable, but obviously that won't work since **you can't name it the same variable**. But my intention was to use it like so:

```
 If color_input = 'GREEN' Then toy_rec := cursr_greens
 If color_input = 'BLUE' Then toy_rec := cursr_blues
 Else NULL
 end if;

 For cursr in toy_rec LOOP
```

I know it's possible to achieve this another way, but my intention is to add as minimal code as possible to the existing code (I didn't want to duplicate the process, etc.)

Thoughts?

Comment: What kind of cursors - how are they defined? Do they have the same columns and data types? Can you have a single parameterised cursor instead?

Comment: Yes they have the exact same columns and data types - and I dfined as collection type (table type). We may need to add different populations so I think single param cursor might get too convoluted.  I'll try ref cursor that  Paul suggested. Thanks!

Comment: You can't swap static cursors like this. Could you use UNION ALL to create one cursor and pick one layer of it at runtime using a parameter?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson oh okay, thanks for letting me know it can't be done that way! The reason I'm avoiding doing your suggestion is because they're coming from different tables/populations and would like to use the same script but just pass in an arbitrary parameter to run a certain population over the other, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with REF CURSORs:

```
DECLARE
  mycur sys_refcursor;
  color_input varchar2(10) := 'GREEN';
  var_dummy varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  IF color_input = 'GREEN'
  THEN
    OPEN mycur FOR SELECT 'foo' FROM dual;
  ELSE
    OPEN mycur FOR SELECT 'bar' FROM dual;
  END IF;
  
  FETCH mycur INTO var_dummy;
  
  WHILE mycur%FOUND
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(var_dummy);
    FETCH mycur INTO var_dummy;
  END LOOP;
  
  CLOSE mycur;
END;
```

You can do the same thing with records:

```
DECLARE
  mycur sys_refcursor;
  color_input varchar2(10) := 'GREEN';
  TYPE dummy_rectype IS RECORD (col1 varchar2(10),col2 varchar2(10),col3 varchar2(10));
  rec_dummy dummy_rectype;
BEGIN
  IF color_input = 'GREEN'
  THEN
    OPEN mycur FOR SELECT 'foo1','foo2','foo3' FROM dual;
  ELSE
    OPEN mycur FOR SELECT 'bar1','bar2','bar3' FROM dual;
  END IF;
  
  FETCH mycur INTO rec_dummy;
  
  WHILE mycur%FOUND
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_dummy.col1||', '||rec_dummy.col2||', '||rec_dummy.col3);
    FETCH mycur INTO rec_dummy;
  END LOOP;
  
  CLOSE mycur;
END;
```

Comment: This looks promising, thank you! I'll give this a try!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if my cursor returns a collection. Any workaround if that's the case?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. What kind of collection?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused with the terminology! It's really a record - I try to declare it as %rowtype but getting errors

Comment: As long as both cursors return the same type, you can fetch a record... just fetch it into a variable of the same record type. Hopefully both your cursors return the same column list. If they don't, you'll have to normalize them somehow so that they do.  Edited my answer to illustrate with records.

Comment: Paul, you are a genius!! It works flawlessly and I like that the code looks clean and minimalistic.